# Repetitive .toggleClass problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, toggleclass

I have some repeating divs that I'm trying to .toggleClass multiple elements on and am having trouble pointing to the right ones without altering others.

Basically I have bunch of divs with the same ids and classes and I only want to toggle each to expand by clicking a link with the class "a_expander". I would like that to toggle the #result class between "a_collapse a_expand, as well as toggle the #resthumb between "rescellLc rescellLe"
it looks like this

```
<div id="result" class="bg_fader scaler a_collapse">
        <div id="resthumb" class="scaler rescellLc">
           <img src="img/fine-fur-coat.png" />
        </div>
            <div class="rescellC">
                <div class="res_content_album-title">
                    <h><a class="a_expander">Fine Fur Coat</a></h>
                    <p>3 Tracks | September 2012</p>
                </div>
</div>
<div id="result" class="bg_fader scaler a_collapse">
        <div id="resthumb" class="scaler rescellLc">
            <img src="img/tunneling.png" />
        </div>
            <div class="rescellC">
                <div class="res_content_album-title">
                    <h><a class="a_expander">Tunneling</a></h>
                    <p>15 Tracks | July 2011</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

and my js so far was

```
$('.a_expander').click(function () {
$(this).siblings('#result').toggleClass("a_collapse a_expand");
$(this).siblings('.resthumb').toggleClass("rescellLc rescellLe");
});
```

I was using the .parent() to get to the outer div but could not change the #resthumb only point to the #result. Hopefully this is not to confusing and someone can help. Much appreciated in advance.

Comment: paste your css here or fiddle it

Comment: @RobM divs don't have names, they can have the same class-names. Perhaps this is what you meant.

Comment: you should not use the same id for multiple div's. id's should be unique in the document.

Comment: The id's don't have css I was just using them for the javascript to locate and toggle the classes. I should just point out this is what I'm trying to do: https://news.google.com/
Basically a list of expandable elements.

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the duplicate IDs as the previous posters indicated. You cannot use the same ID more than once on a given page.

Next replace the calls to .siblings() with calls to .closest(). The #result divs are not siblings of the anchor tags. (siblings in jQuery means that two or more elements are children of the same parent container.) #result is an "ancestor" of the links (not a sibbling, not the parent. more like a great great great grandfather if you will). To get to #result from the anchor you have to go up multiple levels of the DOM. Use .closest() for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lots of things here...

First:
I like the tunes from Emily Peal :).

Second:
 
I recommend that you consider restructuring your HTML -- the sample structure and style names are pretty confusing when trying to figure it out. If you are willing to restructure, I put together an example that does effectively accomplishes the same in a much cleaner way here: 
 ***http://jsfiddle.net/9PFps/2/*** . 
It's cleaner to just do the toggle in one place (for example at the album level) and let the children nodes leverage that to adjust their style. Take a look at the example and you'll see what I mean. BTW, I also added "Bang Bang" and some images for the covers to my example for the sake of completeness. :) 
Here's the snippets:
HTML:

```
<div class="album notSelected">
    <div class="album_title">Fine Fur Coat</div>
    <div class="album_details">
        <div class="album_image">
            <img src="~/img/a3596975827_3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="album_info">
            3 Tracks | September 2012
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<hr />
<div class="album notSelected" >
    <div class="album_title">Tunneling</div>
    <div class="album_details">
        <div class="album_image">
            <img src="~/img/a2007832660_3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="album_info">
            15 Tracks | July 2011
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<hr />
<div class="album notSelected">
    <div class="album_title">Bang Bang</div>
    <div class="album_details">
        <div class="album_image">
            <img src="~/img/a3825495084_3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="album_info">
            1 Track | January 2012
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".album").click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            //The "selected" album was clicked, just toggle it to "notSelected"
            $(this).toggleClass("notSelected selected");
        }
        else {
            //Set all albums to "notSelected" and just toggle the clicked one to "selected"
            $(".album").removeClass("selected notSelected");
            $(".album").addClass("notSelected");
            $(this).toggleClass("notSelected selected");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.album {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.album.notSelected{
    border-style: none;
}

.album.selected {
    border-style: solid;
}

.album_title{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.album.selected .album_title {
    color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.album.notSelected .album_details {
    display: none;
}

.album_image {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Third:
Your existing HTML above isn't well-formed -- you are missing a closing div in your first result. This would lead to problems with jQuery selectors (and likely your layout), depending on what methods you're using.

Finally:
If you really want to use that existing structure, I put together an example of walking the DOM to the nodes whose classes you want to toggle, with some made up styles. You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KSeLL/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much. What you put together is pretty close to what I am doing except that my thumbnail of Emily's album covers are visible as thumbnails in the collapsed state and I want them to expand when I open the div which is why I was trying to toggle 2 elements. That is what I was having trouble with. I was able to get something similar to what you have without a problem, but the toggling 2 items. Also my divs are closed properly in my code, I just made a typo up there when copying it in. I also need to show hidden content which I have not gotten to yet. Essentially http://news.google.com/

Comment: Also I should add in I need my toggle trigger to be the album title, not the entire div.

Comment: Glad to help. Please notice the link in the "Finally" section in my answer. That does toggle two elements individually. I've updated it with the small tweak to show image resizing for the album cover as one of the toggles and put it here: jsfiddle.net/KSeLL/4 Actually, the other sample that has the restructured HTML changes multiple display items too, but only requires making one "toggle" change and then leverages that change at the "parent" down to multiple other items by just have styles for children that are aware of the parent, which makes it easier to manage and understand, in my opinion.